# Bibliography and citations not being generated

Tags: bibtex

I have a document.tex and a bibliography.bib files.

**document.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Random citation \cite{cit2023} embedded in text.
\newpage
\bibliography{"<absolute_path_to_the_file>/bibliography"} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@BOOK{cit2023,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Publisher",
YEAR="2023",
}
```

I want to be able to use references in my Latex document from the bibliography file, but I am getting the log messages:

```
Citation `cit2023' on page 1 undefined,
Empty `thebibliography' environment,
There were undefined references.
```

Shouldn't the bibliography file be loaded and Latex be able to reference it properly?  What is wrong here?

Comment: "What is wrong here?" Did you run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: I don't understand this.  I used BibLatex.

Comment: @Luctex You need to use bibtex for the code as shown in the question, biblatex is a different package with a different syntax. Can you tell us exactly how you compile your document?

Comment: The `ieeetr` bibliography style is utterly incompatible with the `biblatex` package. Your minimal program makes absolutely no mention of loading the `biblatex` package. How exactly do you load it? Given the conflict between `ieeetr` and `biblatex`, which error and/or warning messages do you get?

Comment: your document does not use biblatex. It requires bibtex so you should run pdflatex, then bibtex then pdflatex twice more